# Merging rows in a table HTML

Tags: html-table

can someone help me create this table? I need to write the code in html.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5RJp.png)

I watched many videos, I looked for answers and I couldn't find the exact same table.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(3, 50px) / repeat(6, 100px);
}

.grid>div {
  border: solid 1px #000;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
  margin-right: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div style="grid-column: span 6">1</div>
  <div style="grid-column: span 3">2</div>
  <div style="grid-column: span 3">3</div>
  <div style="grid-column: span 2">4</div>
  <div style="grid-column: span 2">5</div>
  <div style="grid-column: span 2">6</div>
</div>
```